# how to create a login page in magento 1.7?

Tags: php, magento, authentication, magento-1.7

How can I create a new login page in magento 1.7 front-end. The user id and password will be extracted from the table. I want the function of forget password also to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can place following code if you are using cms page

```html
{{block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login"  template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"}}
```

Or if you're using .phtml file then add following line

```html
<?php 
echo $this->getLayou()->createBlock('customer/form_login')->setTemplate('customer/form/mini.login.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

Let me know if you have any further queries.

Thanks,

Sagar

Comment: I am not looking for customer Login. I want complete login code for seller and how can i connect with database?

Comment: You need to create an extension for what you're looking for. I would just first get studies with app/code/core/mage/customer module of native magento functionality. you will find all stuff that you want from model class of this module.